# Check two specific exceptions in a match expression in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, pattern-matching

So I have a Try block in Scala

```
  def fromString(s: String): Option[Pitch] = scala.util.Try {
    val (pitchClassName, octaveName) = s.partition(c => !c.isDigit)
    val octave = if octaveName.nonEmpty then octaveName.toInt else 5
    Pitch(pitchClassIndex(pitchClassName) + octave  * 12)
  } match {
    case scala.util.Success(value) => Some(value)
    case scala.util.Failure(e) => 
    case scala.util.Failure(e) => throw e
  }
```

**Now, I know there's a lot of code here that needs an explanation**. For the purpose of this question though what is needed to know is this:

When creating a Pitch instance with a given note like "D#4" there can be two different exceptions that I want to specifically handle. The first is if the Map pitchClassIndex cannot find the given key pitchClassName, the second is if Pitch argument is outside of a given range.

pitchClassIndex:

```
val pitchClassIndex: Map[String, Int] = pitchClassNames.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

pitchClassNames:

```
val pitchClassNames: Vector[String] = Vector("C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B")
```

So now we enter `s: String` and check whether it has a digit, if so split it into the tuple `val (pitchClassName, octaveName)` If `s = "D#4"` the tuple is now `("D#", "4")`
`val octave = 4` So now when creating our Pitch instance we'll get the value in `pitchClassIndex: Map[String, Int]` from the key `pitchClassName: String = "D#"` (Note here that if pitchClassName does not correspond to a value in pitchClassNames we'll get an exception) we'll then add `octave: Int = 4` first multiplied by 12. `Pitch(51)`
Now the two first lines of Pitch looks like this:

```
case class Pitch(nbr: Int):
  assert((0 to 127) contains nbr, s"Error: nbr $nbr outside (0 to 127)")
```

So if arguments passed into Pitch is outside of the range `(0 to 127)` then throw and AssertionError with error message.

So right now we have **two** cases where it can throw an exception, the first is the assert in the beginning. The second is if `pitchClassIndex(pitchClassName)` takes a key that is not included in `pitchClassNames: Vector[String]` for example "K#". Then it will throw a NoSuchElementException with message: "key not found: K#"

Now as you can see I have an empty Failure case in the match expression where I test the Try statement, in this case I wanna check whether exception e is either the AssertionError or the NoSuchElementException and if it is one of these I wanna print some special text. The last case is for other exceptions. However I'm not quite sure how to test this? Is there something I can write inside the Failure like (e: ???) Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add two case clauses for the two exceptions

```
case Failure(e: AssertionError) => 
  // do something
case Failure(e: NoSuchElementException) => 
  // do something else
case Failure(e) =>
  // goes here for other exceptions
```

If you want to combine them into just one case, you can no longer capture details in the variable `e`, so that may not be an option:

```
case Failure(_: AssertionError) 
      | Failure(_: NoSuchElementException)     => 
   // cannot use `e` anymore
```

I suppose you could resort to `.isInstanceOf`

```
case Failure(e) 
  if e.isInstanceOf[AssertionError] ||
     e.isInstanceOf[NoSuchElementException] =>
   // now `e` is Throwable in here
```